# Show a unary relationship hierarchy in one field in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, hierarchy, recursive-query, relationships

I have a table called "Services" which contains a ServiceID, a ParentID and a Description, where the ParentID is the ServiceID of another record. The data is setup in such a way that it forms a multiple level hierarchy of items and the "Root" items have the ParentID set to zero. How can I have a query with a new field that shows a thread of all the parents up to the root parent for each record. Of course, root items will have this field as blank. Using cars as an example, I would like to have such text inside this field for the entry 'X3' and 'Punto' respectively:

Automobiles > Germany > BMW > 4 Wheel Drive > X3

Automobiles > Italy > FIAT > Front Wheel Drive > Punto

I suspect I should have a function to which I feed the ServiceID and which does the necessary recursion to get me the string value containing the threaded descriptions. Tried Googling unary relations but could not find an example with the code for the function I need.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

Here is what my table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Services](
[ServiceID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ParentID] [int] NULL,
[ServiceDescription] [nvarchar](250) NULL)
```

Comment: You may check my answer on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241936/how-can-i-generate-a-hierarchy-path-in-sql-that-leads-to-a-given-node/14243624#14243624

Comment: I managed to use your example to get a list of paths but could not figure out how to integrate it with my table, although it is what I need. With reference to the update I just added (with the table structure) how would I use your example to get a table like this?: ServiceID, ParentID, ServiceDescription, Path

Comment: @EricZ example is for a single record. The answer I gave below is the same recursive logic but used to build the paths for all records in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generic example. You can copy, paste and run it and it will show you the output. If this works you should be able to modify the table and column values to get it to work for your situation.

```
If      Object_ID('dbo.Services') Is Not Null Drop Table [dbo].[Services];
Create  Table [dbo].[Services] (ServiceID Int Identity(1,1) NOT NULL, ParenServiceID Int NULL, ServiceDescription Nvarchar(250) NULL);

Insert  [dbo].[Services]
Select  null, 'Automobiles'
Union   All
Select  1, 'Germany'
Union   All
Select  2, 'BMW'
Union   All
Select  3, '4 Wheel Drive'
Union   All
Select  1, 'Italy'
Union   All
Select  5, 'FIAT'
Union   All
Select  4, 'X3'
Union   All
Select  6, 'Front Wheel Drive'
Union   All
Select  8, 'Punto';

With    recurCTE As
(
        Select  h.ServiceID, h2.ParenServiceID As nextParent, Convert(Varchar(max),Isnull(h2.ServiceDescription + ' > ','') + h.ServiceDescription) As Hierarchy
        From    [dbo].[Services] h
        Left    Join [dbo].[Services] h2
                On  h.ParenServiceID = h2.ServiceID
        Union   All
        Select  rc.ServiceID, h.ParenServiceID As nextParent, Convert(Varchar(max),Isnull(h.ServiceDescription + ' > ','') + rc.Hierarchy) As Hierarchy
        From    recurCTE rc
        Join    [dbo].[Services] h
                On  rc.nextParent = h.ServiceID
),      orderedResults As
(
        Select  ServiceID, Hierarchy
        From   (Select  Row_Number() Over (Partition By ServiceID Order By Len(Hierarchy) Desc) As lenPriID,
                        ServiceID,
                        Hierarchy
                From    recurCTE) As n
        Where   lenPriID = 1
)
Select  h.*, o.Hierarchy
From    orderedResults o
Join    [dbo].[Services] h
        On  o.ServiceID = h.ServiceID
Where   ServiceDescription In ('X3','Punto');
```

Comment: Thanks. Your example seems to assume that I know what children parents will be entered. Unfortunately I wouldn't know what data will be entered, nor would I know the number of levels.

Comment: No, it doesn't, it assumes the relationship between children and parents. I used the naming convention to make it obvious when looking at the results, but you can change them to whatever you want. The query recursively identifies the path structure for all values in the table. There could be 3 levels or 100 levels.

Comment: OK, sorry for the misunderstanding then. It is clear that I have no idea what you are suggesting and therefore cannot implement it for my application (because I don't know how it works). I'm no SQL expert. Is it possible to have a function and feed it a "ServiceID" value and it returns a "Path" value in the for of an NVARCHAR(500)? I refer to the latest update where I posted the structure of the table.

Comment: Alright @Osprey, this is the best I can do for you bro. This query has been modified for you EXACT situation. Unfortunately to do what you want to do recursion is your best bet. You can way over-engineer it with a bunch of while loops, but this would be a pretty painful performance hit. This does what you want it to do and it does it more or less in an elegant set based solution. I'll write up an explanation of what the recursive CTE is doing if that would be helpful. You should be able to copy the logic below the `With RecurCTE` and below and run it and it should just work.

Comment: Remember, you need to have the statement before the `With recurCTE` ended with a `;` and you can remove the `Where` criteria at the end to get a full list of your table or add criteria there to limit to specific records. Good luck.

Comment: OK, got it to work and it is exactly how I wanted it. Thanks! Apologies for my initial misinterpretation of your code and thanks for introducing me to new SQL concepts I was not familiar with :).

Answer (score 0):

I would use left joins to some reasonable limit (like 20) and then concatatinate the strings:

```
 declare @services table (ServiceID int , ParentID int,[Description] varchar(20))

 insert @services
 select 1,null,'automobiles' union
 select 2,null,'hotels' union
 select 3,1,'Germany' union
 select 4,3,'BMW' union
 select 5,3,'Audi' union
 select 6,2,'Hawaii' union
 select 7,2,'Australia'

 select  

 s.Description+'>'+s2.Description+'>'+isnull(s3.Description,'')+'>'+isnull(s4.Description,'')
 from @services s
 left join @services s2 on (s2.ParentID=s.ServiceID)
 left join @services s3 on (s3.ParentID=s2.ServiceID)
 left join @services s4 on (s4.ParentID=s3.ServiceID)
 left join @services s5 on (s5.ParentID=s4.ServiceID)
```

Comment: Thanks. But as I explained to Love2Learn, your example seems to assume that I know what children and parents will be entered. Unfortunately I don't have that info, nor would I know the number of levels and that is why I need a recursive approach like the one mentioned by EricZ.