# Order data with reflexive association

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

[image]

This table represents a set of technologies and subtechnologies. A technology can contain n subtechnologies and 1 subtecn is contained by one tecn.

I need order this set like this

[image]

I appreciate your help.

Comment: order by FK_idTecnFK, PK_idTecn ??

Comment: How do you want to handle the nulls? Should the name be ordered or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: You need a recursive CTE to compute  hierachy path and order by the path. See example  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241936/how-can-i-generate-a-hierarchy-path-in-sql-that-leads-to-a-given-node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THis could be a solution to your question, without using recursive CTE

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (IdTech INT, IdTechFK INT, Name VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1, NULL, 'FRT'),
(2, 1, 'FRT_1'),
(3, 1, 'FRT_2'),
(4, NULL, 'GSC filters'),
(5, 4, 'GSC filters_1'),
(6, 4, 'GSC filter_2'),
(7, 1, 'FRT_3'),
(8, 1, 'FRT_4'),
(9, NULL, 'Power Control')

SELECT a.IdTech, a.IdTechFK, a.Name
FROM (
SELECT m.IdTech, m.IdTechFK, m.Name, m.IdTech AS r FROM @T AS m
WHERE m.IdTechFK IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT  c.IdTech, c.IdTechFK, c.Name, c.IdTechFK AS r FROM @T AS c
WHERE   c.IdTechFK IS NOT NULL) AS a
ORDER BY a.r, idtech, IdTechFK
```

Result

```
+-------+---------+--------------+
|IdTech |IdTechFK |Name          |
+-------+---------+--------------+
|1      |NULL     |FRT           |
|2      |1        |FRT_1         |
|3      |1        |FRT_2         |  
|7      |1        |FRT_3         |
|8      |1        |FRT_4         |
|4      |NULL     |GSC filters   |  
|5      |4        |GSC filters_1 |
|6      |4        |GSC filter_2  |
|9      |NULL     |Power Control |
+-------+---------+--------------+
```

Comment: This can be solution only if recursion has no more then one level.

Comment: @Serg: I agree on that, I've based my solution on the given data