# Generate view with tree path by column

Tags: sql-server, path, tree

I try to do something like that : [How can I generate a hierarchy path in SQL that leads to a given node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241936/how-can-i-generate-a-hierarchy-path-in-sql-that-leads-to-a-given-node)

I'm on SQL Server 2016.

I have two table, **first one**, for the parent-child dependancies :

```
CREATE TABLE [TREE] (
[ID_CHILD] varchar(8) NOT NULL,
[ID_PARENT] varchar(8) NULL,
[LEFT_VALUE] numeric(8, 0) NULL,
[RIGHT_VALUE] numeric(8, 0) NULL
)
```

The first ID node is "ROOT".
Left and Right value are define like that :

NODE (Left, Right)

```
ROOT (0,13)
- A1 (1,6)
-- B1 (2,3)
-- B2 (4,5)
- A2 (7,12)
-- B3 (8,11)
--- C1 (9,10)

ROOT | NULL | 0 | 13
A1   | ROOT | 1 | 6
B1   | A1   | 2 | 3
B2   | A1   | 4 | 5
A2   | ROOT | 7 | 12
B3   | A2   | 8 | 11
C1   | B3   | 9 | 10
```

Each left-right interval include all left-right child numbers.
My tree have max 10 of depth.

And the **second one**, for the affectation of human ressources in the tree :

```
CREATE TABLE [HR_TREE] (
[ID_HR] varchar(9) NOT NULL,
[ID_NODE] varchar(8) NULL
)
```

Whith some data like that :

```
001664 | A1
001564 | B1
034564 | B1
001224 | C1
001677 | B3
```

**I need you help for create view that show me something like that :**

### MY ATTEMPT :

HOW TO CREATE VIEW [FLAT_HR_TREE] ... ????

```
ID_HR   | T1   | T2   | T3   | T4   | T5   | T6   | T7   | T8   | T9   | T10
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
001664  | ROOT | A1   | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL
001564  | ROOT | A1   | B1   | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL
034564  | ROOT | A1   | B1   | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL
001224  | ROOT | A2   | B3   | C1   | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL
001677  | ROOT | A2   | B3   | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL
```

Thank you for your help !!

Thank you JERRY, I have do that :

```
CREATE VIEW MY_FLAT_TREE AS
with CTE_tree
AS
(
  select ht.ID_HR, t.ID_CHILD, t.ID_PARENT, 1 as rank_
  from TREE t
  INNER JOIN HR_TREE ht ON t.ID_CHILD = ht.ID_NODE
  UNION ALL
  select ct.ID_HR, t.ID_CHILD, t.ID_PARENT, rank_ + 1 AS rank_
  from TREE t
  INNER JOIN CTE_tree ct ON ct.ID_PARENT = t.ID_CHILD
)
SELECT ID_HR, [T1], [T2], [T3], [T4], [T5], [T6], [T7], [T8], [T9], [T10]  
FROM (
  SELECT ID_HR, ID_CHILD, 'T'+ CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID_HR order by rank_ DESC) AS VARCHAR(5)) as rank_
  FROM CTE_tree
)up  
PIVOT  
(
  MIN(ID_CHILD) FOR rank_ IN ([T1],[T2],[T3],[T4],[T5],[T6],[T7],[T8],[T9],[T10])
) AS pvt
```

Comment: Could you share you attempt(s) please?

Comment: Need help for create a view like in my example

Comment: I can't see an example attempt in your question. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Like that ? :) just need help to create a view with data like in the last table I draw !

Comment: That's not an attempt, that's your expected result. Please show us the SQL you wrote to try and get the results your after.

Comment: I don't know how to do that !

Comment: Just paste the SQL into your question, by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54628831/edit) it and then highlight it and click the `{}` button to make it display as code.

Comment: I know how to edit my post, but I don't know where to start for solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below solution for your problem:

```
with CTE_tree
AS
(
select ht.id_hr, t.id_child, t.id_parent, 1 as rank_
from TREE t
INNER JOIN [THR_TREE] ht ON t.id_child = ht.id_node
UNION ALL
select ct.id_hr, t.id_child, t.id_parent, rank_ + 1 AS rank_
from TREE t
INNER JOIN CTE_tree ct ON ct.id_parent = t.id_child
)
SELECT id_hr, id_child, 'T'+ CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id_hr order by rank_ DESC) AS VARCHAR(5)) as rank_
INTO #temp_tree
FROM CTE_tree

select id_hr, [T1], [T2], [T3], [T4], [T5], [T6], [T7], [T8], [T9], [T10]  
FROM (
SELECT id_hr, id_child , rank_ 
FROM #temp_tree )up  
PIVOT  
(
MIN(id_child) FOR rank_ IN ([T1],[T2],[T3],[T4],[T5],[T6],[T7],[T8],[T9],[T10])) AS pvt 
ORDER BY id_hr
```